# Android Studio - Images Expand Buttons (and break weight rules?)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imagebutton

I have been working around an issue for far too long. Any time I drop an image into an ImageButton, the button expands to be very large. To try to fix this, I created a TableLayout with TableRows, where the TableLayout has a weightSum and the rows each have their own layout_weight. However, regardless of how much weight that I assign a row, the image blows up and compresses all of my other rows. In other words, the TableRows do not respect the layout_weight assigned to them.

Below, I have four rows with weights 4, 5, 3, 1, respectively. The ImageButton is in the 3rd row with layout_weight="3". However, as you can see, the row expands to fit the button image.

[image: Preview]

At any rate, this is a major issue when I have multiple buttons on the screen. I have created many buttons of the same exact size thinking that I would make them large, so they will scale well with larger devices. Once again, the problem is that they don't scale down to fit inside of a button, but they expand the button, destroying all of the layout_weights in the process.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="13"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_users_view">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"/>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5">
            <ScrollView>
                <!-- Figure out button first -->
            </ScrollView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_cancel_button"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

In addition - This issue may be in part with how I am storing my images. I have saved everything into my drawable folder, but nothing inside my mipmap folders. Though, I did try saving this cancel button into the mipmap-mdpi folder and loading it into the ImageButton, but the effect was exactly the same. Mipmap folders probably just set resolution, not size? I didn't expand my drawable folder because there are maybe 50 images/selectors inside.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was working with a single layout size with a single drawable sized button. The fact is, there are different screen densities, and different images should go to each. For those new to android programming, you can see my project folders transform to be what they "should have been" from the start. Take a look below.

As a short note - androd:layout_weight="1" for example, refers to how important that layout is to the entire layout. Widgets or layouts with lower layout_weights are HIGHER PRIORITY than those with higher layout_weights. As far as I know know, weightSum and layout_weight aren't related, like I thought they were in my XML example.

[image]
_

I created different sized images and put them in their respective folders, where the first drawable folder is used for "selectors" only. Each folder has the same images, just 80 percent smaller than the last folder. Android automatically takes the correct image for you and adds it to the layout preview you are working with. Once I had all of the images for each folder size, I compressed the files, then added them to android studio. I no longer had any issues running my program on ANY phone. Not to mention it was a lot easier to work with my buttons since they weren't physically MASSIVE in size for small phones, and normal sized for XLarge devices.

If issues still persist with out of memory errors, one could increase the heap size in the manifest.xml, but it doesn't seem necessary unless you are making a game. I tried increasing the heap in my super small program, and I could see a speed difference on some devices - the lesson here is to avoid largeHeap="true" unless you REALLY need it

The bottom line is that, if you want a good program, there aren't shortcuts. Learning libraries such as Picasso take time as well. Pick your poison.

On a final note, you can see that there are now 4 layout folders. Each of them contained XML files that were programmed independently so that everything looks the same for each screen density. If we are being honest here, this was mostly copying and pasting with minor modifications to each XML. When making the XML files inside each folder, you name them the files the same names. So activityMain.xml would be created in all 4 folders, and the device running the application would pick the correct XML layout from the folder that the device see's fit for it's screen density. Quite amazing actually.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ImageButton
android:layout_width="XXdp"
android:layout_height="XXdp"
android:background="@drawable/selector_cancel_button"/>
```

Set a specific density pixel for your ImageButton, it will limit it from expanding.

This answer is more like a **HACK**. The right way to do it is to have respective different images for all your screen sizes.

ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhpdi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi. There are multiple open threads here on Stack on how to achieve that. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best that I can recommend you is to get your images sliced on the highest resolution you are targeting, let's say your higher resolution you are targeting is 1080x1920. Get you screen designed on this resolution and get the images on the actual size from this screen design. Put that images in respective "drawable" not "mipmap" like for 1080x1920 the respective folder is "drawable-xxhdpi". Access your images though drawable folder and then you don't even need to use weights or even fixed sizes. It will work like a charm.

Comment: I actually only have one drawable folder - I guess i'll have to create the drawable-xxhdpi (and others). But, of course, i've also had issues with phones crashing when trying to load in my images.

Is is like this - the smaller the screen, the less chance the image can load a larger file? Are resources set aside for larger screen density that smaller screens don't allow?

Comment: yeah you have to create that folder in res. The app must be crashing due to some othet issues,  using large images on small screen doesn't cause the app to crash.

Comment: it's trying to allocate 18 megabytes for images that are in total less than 1 megabyte, it's an android issue that really needs to be fixed.